# How to transfer data from Windows service to the HTML5 web page?

Tags: flash, google-chrome-extension, html5-video, video-capture, google-nativeclient

I have an application that works with web camera. It is developed as Singleton Com Server and runs as **Windows** Service. Its builds a simple DirectShow Graph and do something.

I need to **show video preview** on the html5 web-page in **Chrome**.

The question is **how to transfer data** (for preview) from Windows service to the HTML5 web page?

What solution will be suitable in my case?

- Chrome extension
- PPAPI plugin with NaCl
- Maybe we can use Adobe Flash (but anyway, how to build data exchange
  between flash and Windows application?)
- Or is it possible to create memory-mapped file shared between Chrome
  Extension and windows service?
- something else?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This question is too broad, but take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging

Comment: I check NativeMessaging aproach, it works only for small frame size (72*72 pixels), and for 640*480 I have error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" on extension side.

Comment: Impossible to say without looking at your code, but another approach (probably more efficient) would be to make your service (or a proxy for it) a WebSockets server. Then your HTML5 app will be able to connect and stream data.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you look at using the Portable NaCl plugin. There is an example that comes with the sdk that streams video from a webcam. From the sdk:

"The MediaStream Video example demonstrates how to capture video from
  a webcam."

See here for getting started.

https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/tutorial/tutorial-part1

Comment: Except this solution means "Throw away your app and rewrite it from scratch". It does not solve "how to connect to an existing service"